# What is the Unity 2019.3.5 version of `UnityEngine.UI.Text`?

Tags: unity, gui, text, unity-ui

I was following a tutorial on how to create a dialogue Box in Unity, and in one part of the tutorial the tutor imports `UnityEngine.UI` and creates an object of type `Text`, but my version of Unity is 2019.3.5f1 and I learned through searching a bit online that this `UnityEngine.UI` doesn't exist anymore in this version, and that it was replaced with
`UnityEngine.UIElements`, and this `Text` type doesn't exist anymore as well.

I couldn't find a replacement for `Text` or what is the new nomenclature, nothing from trying stuff that popped in the auto complete or searching for answers in the Internet gave me answers. Maybe I just searched poorly, but if anyone happens to know, could you kindly answer?

Comment: Try Adding "TextMeshPro". It ships as part of Unity...  Window -> TextMeshPro -> Import Essentials. You'll then have a control of type `TextMeshProUGUI` (in code) which has a `.Text` property and all the other things you'd expect, as well as very decent font support. You'll also be able to add components of type "TextMeshPro" to your UI elements if you prefer Drag+Drop to coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still the same.

`UnityEngine.UI` didn't go away, **it's just considered a package now,** so [its documentation has moved out of the core and into its own sub-page.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Text.html)

Open your Package Manager window, and install/update the Unity UI package if it's not installed or out of date.

[image: Unity UI in the Package Manager]

Now adding `using UnityEngine.UI;` at the top of your script will let you access the `Text` type just like in the tutorial.

(Though for many purposes you'd likely prefer the `TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI` type, which does the same thing but with signed distance field rendering that tends to look more crisp, and offers more powerful styling options. Add the TextMeshPro package to use this one.)

Comment: Thank you! Unity is fine now with the Text, it's working but the vs code is still reporting error, it's not recognizing the UI, is there a way for me to make vs code recognize it? So it stops giving me false errors. I tried using the Assembly file and creating a reference for the UI because I heard of this but I can't find the dll.

Comment: I know struggling with intillisense in VS Code is a common problem, but I don't use it myself so I don't have any leads for you. Try checking other answers here on the topic.